How can I make simple AM modulator?
I've been trying to get to make this simple am diode modulator work, but it seems like when I give the modulator RF signal from simple crystal generator and audio, it works a bit but the modulation is very weak, (only if I give it very high audio voltage, above 1V ), so does someone know what I can do to make this modulator work more properly or know any other circuit that will do the trick? I know I can make just audio amplifier but I think there is also better way to do that.
The modulator I am using (Image source: https://slideplayer.com/slide/5764212/, published by: Amberlynn Alexander):



does someone know what I can do to make this modulator work more
properly or know any other circuit that will do the trick?

Stay simple is my advice. Here's a single diode AM modulator from an earlier answer of mine: -



Probably the main thing you missed in your modulator was a little bit of DC biasing. You can make the 1:1 buffer using an NPN emitter follower. Having just rechecked the simulation, you can bypass the buffer completely without much deterioration of the modulation purity.
If you remove the DC offsets (V3 and V4) from the carrier and modulating signal it will still work but at a slightly reduced amplitude.

Thank you very much byt there is one think i dont understand, why did you put audio signal to the "output" of the diode? In all of the circuits i found both signals were put in one point.

@edziograczer the question here is: do you understand why your diode is fit to act as modulator?

@edziograczer I wanted to make a "minimum circuit" just to prove the point that you do not need complication to make a pretty reasonable modulator. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

I just found out your circuit does not work, maybe the idea is okay but in reality the values of resistors are too high and the voltage in output is about 70 - 80 mV

@edziograczer hm, the simulation does work, so your claim that the circuit doesn't work might be because you didn't build or operate it correctly.

@edziograczer you know i can help you figure this out without you having to cancel the answer acceptance as a means of putting pressure on me. I don't respond that that type of pressure.

I didn't mean to put pressure on you, i just thought that if it probably doesn't work, i can cancel it by the time it's resolved, I didn't know it is that serious, sorry. I did this simulation in ltspice and it probably doesn't work because the resistors limit too much current, the impedance of the lc resonant circuit is far less than 10k, and simulation ignores it making about 70mA on the lc resonant circuit, but only pouring less than 1mA from the carrier.

Please show your exact circuit and values in a comment link to an image. Please don't alter your question @edziograczer

L1 and C1 need to be reasonably tuned to the frequency of the carrier wave if that helps.

But you already know what you need to do to make the modulator work well: the modulating signal needs to be strong.
This, by the way, is not a very good modulator; but you are probably aware of that.

I am, in fact, , so what modulator would be better?

probably something that deliberately biases a transistor into a region where it reacts quadratically to its input, and then keeping the input small relative to the bias. Furthermore, the output filtering should be more restrictive and less load on the nonlinear element.

A simple AM modulator can be realized using a classical BJT-based differential amplifier with a third transistor in the common emitter leg (acting as a current source).
Any signal at the base of the 3rd transistor will modify the collector current for both amplifying transistors and, hence, the voltage gain of the stage.
As a result - the amplitude of the amplifiers output voltage swings according to the modulating signal at the 3rd transistor.
